# Ruby on Rails Tutorial /articles/new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following this tutorial
  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html, I'm on section 5.1, but I don't see a directory for /articles/new/. Am I supposed to create this or should this already have been done when I added `resources :articles` to `config/routes.rb`? My `/config/routes.rb` looks like:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'welcome#index'
  resources :articles
  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you've skipped this bit in section 4.2: `$ bin/rails generate controller welcome index`

Answer (score 2):

Did you generate your **articles** controller?

When you generate a controller it should create a directory in your view but will not have any erb files in it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create the files manually, but it is better to do it the rails way so you need to **generate the articles controller and pass it the views you want to have**.

As an example:

`rails g controller articles index new show edit`

This creates your **articles_controller** with the proper **methods** already there for you to work with, as well as the **views**, that is what the rails generators does!

The generator also created **get routes in the routes.rb file**, so make sure to delete those get routes, because you already are handling the routes with `resources :articles`.